# Jquery hover on div, add styles on grandparent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

I have a big problem and I cant find the solution...

I must do the tooltip, for example we have this structure:

```
<body> 
  **<div class="tooltip">Long text ...</div>**
  <div style="overflow:hidden">
    <div class="box">
      **<h1>Short text</h1>**
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

And if I am on `h1` I want add to `div` with class tooltip `visibility:visible`, how can I do this?

I hope you find the solution to this problem.

Comment: use `$('h1').closest('.tooltip').css({'visibility':'visible'})`

Comment: Is that HTML structure required, or can it be changed to become easier to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jquery [`.hover()`](https://api.jquery.com/hover/) for as `h1` and [`.prepend()`](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) for adding `div` with class `.tooltip` and `visibility: visible` something like below

```js
$('h1').hover(function() {
  var tooltip = document.getElementsByClassName('tooltip');
  if(!tooltip[0]) {
    $('body')
    .prepend('<div class="tooltip" style="visibility:visible;">Long text ...</div>');
  }
});
```

```css
.tooltip {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body> 
  ****
  <div style="overflow:hidden">
    <div class="box">
      **<h1>Short text</h1>**
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Hope this will help you in some way(y).

Answer (score 0):

Since your `tooltip` isn't a parent of the `h1` you've to go up two levels then get the previous element with the class `tooltip` :

```
$('h1').parent().parent().prev('.tooltip').css({'visibility':'visible'});
```

You could use `hover()` method to toggle the `visibility` :

```
$('h1').hover(function(){
    $(this).parent().parent().prev('.tooltip').css({'visibility':'visible'});
},function(){
    $(this).parent().parent().prev('.tooltip').css({'visibility':'hidden'});
})
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$('h1').hover(function(){
  $(this).parent().parent().prev('.tooltip').css({'visibility':'visible'});
},function(){
  $(this).parent().parent().prev('.tooltip').css({'visibility':'hidden'});
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tooltip" style="visibility:hidden">Long text ...</div>
<div style="overflow:hidden">
  <div class="box">
    <h1>Short text</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @norbertturekpl is that not what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

When you hover to H1 and you want to add tooltip to the grand parent this will be the answer.

```
$('.box h1').mouseenter(function() {
   $(this.parentNode.parentNode.previousElementSibling).addClass('tooltip');
});

//2nd option
$('.box h1').mouseenter(function() {
   $(this.parentNode.parentNode.previousElementSibling).css('visibility', 'visible');
});
```

Read this to know what target you want to use the event/script [W3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_all.asp)